# run automatically t4 templates

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-generation, t4

I would like to know if is possible to run a T4 template when saving a other file, example run my .tt file after/on saving a xml file

I forgot to mention that my IDE is VS2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. [Here is how](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/11/t4-toolbox-automatic-template-transformation/).

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your great T4Toolbox, Is there any simple way to seprate .tt file from the triggerer file? 
The main problem with the mentioned solution is if you change the filename , it drop the related .tt file too without any permission!

Comment: Link now gives 404.

Comment: link is 404 and the solution should not be a link