# How to automatically run custom tool for T4 file when another file is saved

Tags: visual-studio, t4

Is there a way to automatically run the T4 transform when another file is saved?

Comment: This seems to be the same question as [run automatically t4 templates](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3948248/1380680)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [AutoRunCustomTool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ecb123bf-44bb-4ae3-91ee-a08fc1b9770e) Visual Studio extension was created to address this exact scenario.

Comment: Hello, I would like to ask you as an author of this extension. Do you plan to maintain this extension for future versions of Visual Studio? e.g. VS 2015? I just started to use your extension and it seems to be great. Your last version is from 11/2013 (version 2.0.1). Thank you

Comment: @user2126375, yes, I'm still maintaining it, I just didn't need to modify it since 2013. I haven't checked if it works in VS2015 yet, but I'll make sure it does.

Comment: Thanks for info. I tested AutoRunCustomTool in VS 2015 RC and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like T4 Toolbox is not available for VS2012. However there is now a feature in tangible T4 Editor that allows you to simply add a auto-transformed template to any exisitng file in your solution so that when the parent file is saved the dependend t4 file is transformed. See here:

http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/blog/dependent-t4-templates.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [T4 Toolbox](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7f9bd62f-2505-4aa4-9378-ee7830371684). Select the file in Solution Explorer and set the `Custom Tool Template` in the Properties window.

I get this answer form [How can set the custom tool property of an xml file to a T4 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997308/how-can-set-the-custom-tool-property-of-an-xml-file-to-a-t4-file/15037150#15037150)