# How can set the `custom tool` property of an xml file to a T4 file?

Tags: asp.net, xml, visual-studio, t4, resx

we know that asp.net .resx files have an custom tool for generating some c# code (**ResXFileCodeGenerator**).

I have an xml file and I want to set the custom tool property of that to a **T4** file.

how can i bind T4 file to the xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [T4 Toolbox](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7f9bd62f-2505-4aa4-9378-ee7830371684). Select the resx file in Solution Explorer and set the Custom Tool Template in the Properties window.

Comment: thats work fine, but I work in a team and don't want to force our member for installing an VS Extension! are you have a solution for that?

Comment: In that case, you should probably stick with the built-in resx file generator.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/t4editor_features.html#Compare. There's a feature called "Add Code Generation Item Command" that might do the trick.

Comment: thanks but that's not exist in free edition. how can i implement that?